# How can I plot a collapsible tree with various levels in R?

Tags: r, tree, powerbi

I have been trying to plot a collapsible tree with `collapsibletree` package but I don't get what I need. Also, this plot should be uploaded to power BI using the R script visual feature.

Imagine that I have a dataframe like this:

```
parent <- c("", "Carlos", "Carlos", "María", "María", "Paula", "Alex")
child <- c("Carlos", "María", "Alex", "Javier", "Paula", "Pablo", "Pepe")

df <- data.frame(parent, child)
```

And then, I want to plot a collapsible tree:

```
collapsibleTree(df = df,
                hierarchy = c("parent", "child"),
                root = "Carlos")
```

But I get this result:

[image]

And the result I want is this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to get that solution?

Thanks in advance and have a great day!!

Answer (score 1):

You should have one value as `NA` in your data, because you need to have a beginning point. That's why I changed your `""` in the `parent` vector to `NA`. After that you can use the following code:

```
parent <- c(NA, "Carlos", "Carlos", "María", "María", "Paula", "Alex")
child <- c("Carlos", "María", "Alex", "Javier", "Paula", "Pablo", "Pepe")

df <- data.frame(parent, child)

library(collapsibleTree)
collapsibleTreeNetwork(df, collapsed = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I can't plot it in Power BI because it is not a png output... I have tried creating another organization chart with igraph package but every time anyone of the organization chart changes, you have to modify the R code (because yo need to specify the nodes and directions for every employee)

Comment: @Alex, you can easily save the plot as `png` in RStudio. Check this link how to export the plot as png:https://r-coder.com/save-plot-r/